# Distributing iPhone app for testing without visible source code

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an iPhone application that I am required to distribute for testing, but I do not want to make the source code visible. Is there a way that I can freely distribute the app without the source code being visible? Also I can not sign up for a developer account, because, primarily, I don't have time to.

- I should also mention that all the testing will be on simulators, so basically I would like to compile to code to arbitrarily run on an iOS simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run your app in simulator on your computer.
2. Look for Folder:
   /Users/your_user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/[D58FCF16-FD9A-45B5-867D-F2A05184A899]/YourApp.app
3. Copy and archive all folder with your app.
4. Send to QA team.

Them have to close simulator, place this folder at the same path on QA computer, and launch the simulator. 
Your app will be on the springboard of simulator.